# pass eventdata to event handler in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two div :

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

and i have the following jquery for div1:

```
 $('#div1').click(function(e)
{
alert(e.pageX + ' ' + e.pageY);
});
```

.
Now, i want to trigger click eventhandler of div1 to execute on clcicking of div2.
For this i wrote:

```
$('div2').click(function(e)
{
$('#div1').trigger('click');
});
```

It's working fine but the problem is i am not able to get e.pageX and e.pageY in the event handler of div1.
How to pass eventdata of div2 click event handler i.e e to div1 click event handler.
Please help.

Comment: Woah, what happened with the title? I can only assume that was a mistake.

Comment: I don't think it is possible due to the trigger function only running the function you specified and not actually firing the event. This means that pageX/Y will not exist. `e` won't even exist.

Comment: @Wolfy, `e` does exist as jQuery creates one as part of `.trigger()` but `pageX` and `pageY` will be undefined.

Comment: @Niraj, no worries, it just made me read the question 5 times ;)

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for clearing that up. I don't use jQuery too much anymore :]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the event you want to trigger is of the same type, you can pass the old event object right along:

```
$('#div2').click(function (e) {
    $('#div1').trigger(e);
});
```

For events of a different type, you may create a custom event object:

```
$('#div2').mouseenter(function (e) {
    var newE = jQuery.Event('click');
    newE.pageX = e.pageX;
    newE.pageY = e.pageY;
    $('#div1').trigger(newE);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuerys `.trigger()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)</sup> should be the answer here. You can pass in event-strings (along with parameters) aswell as **event objects**.

```
$('#div2').click(function(e) {
    $('#div1').trigger(e);
});
```